# Grouping HTML elements by order in document

Tags: python

I have an HTML document that goes something like this:

```
<div class = "Group"> Group 1 </div>
<div class = "item"> Item 1 </div>
<div class = "Group"> Group 2 </div>
<div class = "item"> Item 2 </div>
<div class = "item"> Item 3 </div>
```

I want to create a list of each item that belongs to the group group element that proceeds them:

```
Group 1: [Item 1]
Group 2: [Item 2, Item 3]
```

Normally it's easy to do this, but I'm not sure how to approach when elements aren't nested accurately. I instead need to do this by only selecting HTML that appears below an element, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: you can get elements one-by-one, if it is `Group` then save old list and create new one, if it `Item` then add to list. At start "old list" can be `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Although it could be done with `re` or other methods, html parsing requires a suitable library.
Using `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class = "Group"> Group 1 </div>
<div class = "item"> Item 1 </div>
<div class = "Group"> Group 2 </div>
<div class = "item"> Item 2 </div>
<div class = "item"> Item 3 </div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
data = {}
key = None
for i in soup.find_all('div'):
    if 'Group' in i.get('class'):
        key = i.text.strip()
        data[key] = []
    elif key:
        data[key].append(i.text.strip())

print(data)
```

---

```
{'Group 2': ['Item 2', 'Item 3'], 'Group 1': ['Item 1']}
```